# Why do I get "Notice: Undefined offset" from arrays passed as arguments?

Tags: php, arrays, function

What am I doing wrong here that is causing me to get this message?

```
function numbered_array( $array ) {    
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $array ); $i++ ) {
        echo $i . ": ";
        echo $array[$i] . "<br/>\n";
    }
}
```

I only have this problem from inside a function. When I use the same code on its own, e.g.

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $my_array ); $i++ ) {
    echo $i . ": ";
    echo $my_array[$i] . "<br/>\n";
}
```

it works just fine.

I seem to be having this issue with ANY function to which arrays are passed as arguments.

(For reference, I am working with a 1 dimensional array of string values)

Comment: Why not just use a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)? You can get just the value, or the key/value pair, and you won't have to worry about non-sequential keys.

Comment: In the specific case above that would be easy. But once I'm comparing multiple values between multiple arrays it's a lot easier to work with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem.

```
function numbered_array(array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ": ";
        echo $value . "<br/>\n";
    }
}

$array = array("test","test","test","test",);

numbered_array($array);
```

Output

```
0: test<br/>
1: test<br/>
2: test<br/>
3: test<br/>
```

Comment: I still don't really understand why the problem occurred, but at least I know how to get around it.

Comment: Usually offset error accords, when you try to access an array with a key that doesn't exist. But your code has no issues, when I test it out. It might be that the array that you have given to the function accord an error.